# Japanese cartoon about a boy from Earth who grew up on an alien planet where the people use a ring to change their appearance

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I am looking for the title of a Japanese sci-fi cartoon I saw when I was young, but now I do not remember it anymore. The story is about a boy from Earth who grew up on a alien planet where the inhabitants can change their semblances by applying a ring, but that ring did not have effect on him.

Later in his teens he is told that Earth is a very violent and belligerent planet, eager to dominate the whole universe. At some point some pirates from Earth land on that planet and wanted to loot it but the boy starts fighting, while the inhabitants turn themselves into animals not to get caught. He is then kidnapped by the pirates and a long adventure starts, at the end of which he reaches Earth, rebuilding human society in a more fair manner.

I also remember that Earth had been dominated by a computer, that the boy was the son of two opponents of that system which were killed by the government and that during the trip they land on a planet called Sirius 8, where the inhabitants have vegetable traits. The cartoon is a film of about 2 hrs.

Comment: When someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [Bander Book: The One Million Year Trip](https://cartoonresearch.com/index.php/the-tezuka-pro-tv-specials-1978-1989-1-banders-book/)?

From Cartoon Research:

> The Earth **space pirate** Black Jack comes to their world ahead of
> the regular Earth armies, to rob rather than to conquer. **Bander
> tells everyone to change into animals and flee**, while he will stay
> in the palace to fight them.

And:

> Bander and Muzu follow the Silicon gang (the humorous Western villains
> who are Earth’s puppets) to the castle-hideout of their leader, Don
> Dracula. Bander, while defeating Don Dracula (with brief parodies of
> notable scenes from Forbidden Planet and The Exorcist), rescues
> Princess Marina, the daughter of King Borbo VII of the planet **Sirius
> 8**. Bander and Muzu take her home in one of the Silicon gang’s spaceships. They find that Sirius 8 is under the more blatant rule of
> Earth, with General Dokudami, the Earth Federation’s ambassador,
> giving orders to King Borbo. It was Dokudami who had Princess Marina
> kidnapped and brought to Don Dracula. Dokudami has his henchman Hamegg
> throw Bander into the dungeon under the palace. Another prisoner, Dr.
> Sharaku (Tezuka’s Three-Eyed Boy), who knows the history of Earth,
> tells Bander in a pastiche of the “Rite of Spring” sequence of
> Disney’s Fantasia.

And:

> ...they find that Earth, still under the influence of the distilled
> terror, is ruled in the name of “science” by MOTHER, **a giant
> computer**...

Comment: Yes, that was it! I had been looking for this cartoon for decades. Thanks a lot!